# Android, basic code testing without emulator

Tags: android, testing

I'm developing an Android app on a relatively slow computer that can't handle the emulator very well, and I am without an Android phone.

I looked at Roboelectric, but literally all I want to be able to do at this point is run my application and Log to the command line. What is the best testing framework to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The best solution is to either get a faster computer to run the emulator or get an Android device, perhaps both. You cannot run apps without an emulator or Android device. Robolectric can help with unit testing, but only to a point, since most of the SDK is simply mock objects in Robolectric.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator and Robolectric are pretty much the only games in town. That's the state of the art of testing on Android I'm afraid. Sorry!